# Как поменять значение переменной в браузере? Javascript

Tags: javascript

Есть переменная var a = 0;
Как через prompt задать любое число и это число присвоилось переменной a?

Answer (score 1):

```js
result = prompt(title, [default]);
```

Даже в [документации](https://learn.javascript.ru/alert-prompt-confirm) это написано.

**prompt**

Функция prompt принимает два аргумента:

`result = prompt(title, [default]);`

Этот код отобразит модальное окно с текстом, полем для ввода текста и кнопками OK/Отмена.

**title**

Текст для отображения в окне.

**default**

Необязательный второй параметр, который устанавливает начальное значение в поле для текста в окне.

> Квадратные скобки в синтаксисе [...] Квадратные скобки вокруг default
> в описанном выше синтаксисе означают, что параметр факультативный,
> необязательный.

Пользователь может напечатать что-либо в поле ввода и нажать OK. Введённый текст будет присвоен переменной result. Пользователь также может отменить ввод нажатием на кнопку «Отмена» или нажав на клавишу Esc. В этом случае значением result станет null.

Вызов prompt возвращает текст, указанный в поле для ввода, или null, если ввод отменён пользователем.

Например:

```
let age = prompt('Сколько тебе лет?', 100);

alert(`Тебе ${age} лет!`); // Тебе 100 лет!
```

> Для IE: всегда устанавливайте значение по умолчанию Второй параметр
> является необязательным, но если не указать его, то Internet Explorer
> вставит строку "undefined" в поле для ввода.
>
> Запустите код в Internet Explorer и посмотрите на результат:
>
> `let test = prompt("Test");` Чтобы prompt хорошо выглядел в IE,
> рекомендуется всегда указывать второй параметр:
>
> `let test = prompt("Test", ''); // <-- для IE`

Comment: Тем не менее, просили ввести число.

Comment: @Qwertiy ну там примерные данные были в вопросе. Число это или условие под регулярку - не важно. Дальше он может сам разобраться. Тем более вопрос состоят именно в том, как вывести значение из `prompt` в переменную

Answer (score 0):

```
let a = 0;

a = +prompt('Введите значение переменной a');
alert(a);
alert(typeof a);
```

Comment: Число же просили.

Comment: Я думал, что автор сам разберется с преобразованием типов, но рас уж нет, я отредактировал ответ.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var a = prompt("Enter a")
if (a !== null) a = +a
console.log(a)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin спасибо что указали на мои ошибки , да, признаю был не прав